# Почему wall.get выдает пустые объекты java sdk vk?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, sdk

Использую Java SDK:

```
try {
    GetResponse getQuery = vk.wall().get(actor)
        .ownerId(-9165838) 
        .offset(0)
        .count(10)
        .filter(WallGetFilter.ALL)
        .execute();
    System.out.println(getQuery);
} catch (ApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но результат всегда такой:

```
GetResponse{
    count=3983, 
    items=[
        WallpostFull{
            copyHistory=null,
            canEdit=null,
            createdBy=null,
            canDelete=null,
            canPin=null,
            isPinned=1,
            comments=CommentsInfo{count=0, canPost=1}, 
            likes=LikesInfo{
                count=0,
                userLikes=0,
                canLike=1,
                canPublish=1
            },
            reposts=RepostsInfo{count=0, userReposted=0}
        },

        WallpostFull{
            copyHistory=null,
            canEdit=null,
            createdBy=null,
            canDelete=null,
            canPin=null,
            isPinned=null,
            comments=CommentsInfo{count=0, canPost=1}, 
            likes=LikesInfo{
                count=0,
                userLikes=0,
                canLike=1,
                canPublish=0
            },
            reposts=RepostsInfo{count=0, userReposted=0}
        },

        WallpostFull{
            copyHistory=null,
            canEdit=1,
            createdBy=854708,
            canDelete=1,
            canPin=null,
            isPinned=null,
            comments=CommentsInfo{count=0, canPost=1}, 
            likes=LikesInfo{
                count=0,
                userLikes=0,
                canLike=1,
                canPublish=0
            },
            reposts=RepostsInfo{count=0, userReposted=0}
        }, 

        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Судя по коду ответы возвращаются не пустые. Если речь идет о свойствах со значением `null`, то я не уверен, но причина может быть в недоступности этой информации для пользователя, чей токен использует приложение.

Comment: Похоже дело не в доступе. Попробовал получить из своей группы, но результат странный... В ответе видны тексты репостов на стене, а самих постов по прежнему нет.

Answer (score 0):

Класс WallpostFull наследуется от Wallpost.

Код `System.out.println(getQuery);` вызывает метод toString() у объекта WallpostFull, который не отражает всей информации о Wallpost.

Т.е. данные есть, это просто toString() не отображает всей информации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я впервые с json столкнулся. Я так понял, что нужно получить объект Wallpost? А как это сделать?

Comment: Нет, в этом нет необходимости. Просто используйте get'еры для доступа к данным: getText(), getAttachments() и т.д. Н-р: `getQuery.getItems().get(0).getText()`